# What is link graph database

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, graph-databases, apache-tika

While checking documentation of some of the open source web crawlers like Apache Nutch, Apache Tika; I frequently encountered "link graph database" term. Can anyone summarize about it?

Answer (score 0):

Nutch is open source web-search software. It builds on Lucene Java, adding web-specifics, **such as** a crawler, **`a link-graph database`**, parsers for HTML and other document formats, etc. Its main feature include...

Nutch work together with a link-graph database. If you don't know anything about graph database, you can examine [here](http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2013/02/04/what-are-the-differences-between-relational-and-graph-databases). There are more than one graph database. Ex : [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) ,[infogrid](http://infogrid.org/trac/)